# How can I parse some json files to a List<Map> in dart?

Tags: json, parsing, serialization, dart, flutter

I wrote [this code](https://pastebin.com/qWc7Lx04) to do it. My API is completely working and has no problem. My code is working when I want to print one of `Product class` fields but it's not working when I want to parse all of my json file to a Map and add it to a list. This is the error:

```
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: add(Instance of 'Product')
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
#1      ProductNetwork.fetchProduct
package:dart_project/product.dart:62
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      main
package:dart_project/main.dart:5
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure>  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:300:19)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:171:12)
Exited (255)
```

what's the problem of my [code](https://pastebin.com/qWc7Lx04)?

Comment: Please don't use an external link to show your code. Instead, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your code *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working because you're asking for a `List` in the constructor of `ProductNetwork`, but not passing one, so your `List` is going to be null and `add` method won't work on null. You're actually initializing the `List` right after its declaration, but this initialization will be overridden by the constructor's, which is null. Either remove the `List` from the constructor or pass a `List` to it.

This should work:

```dart
void main() async {
  ProductNetwork productNetwork = ProductNetwork();
  var data = await productNetwork.fetchProduct();
  print(data.toString());
}

class ProductNetwork {
  List<Product> allProducts = List<Product>();

  Future<List<Product>> fetchProduct() async {
    int productId = 0;
    String url =
        'http://example.com/api/Product/GetProduct?id=${productId.toString()}';
    final http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200)
      await allProducts.add((Product.fromJson(json.decode(response.body))));
    else
      throw Exception('Failed. Status Code: ${response.statusCode}');
    return allProducts;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "ProductNetwork({this.allProducts});"